# passing list of objects in controller using ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to passing List to controller method using ajax. example I am 2 objects in the list like below. I am getting two objects in controller but inside properties are `null`

```
 var dataObject = { 'sections': sectionsOrder};
        console.log(dataObject);
    CustomAjaxRequest("Post", "@Url.Action("UpdateOrderHoldingsForSections", "Renewal")" , 
         dataObject, "json", "UpdateSectionsViewWithLatestOrderHoldings", 
               null, true);


   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateOrderHoldingsForSections(List<OrderHoldings> sections)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

even I tried `var dataObject = { 'sections': json.stringify(sectionsOrder)};` still nothing working. What could be the problem?

In Console before passing values

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Without the full model (in js and in C#) it's very hard to tell what's happening, add it to the code.

Comment: What is your `CustomAjaxRequest()` method? Your ajax options need to be `data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),` and `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is expecting a List, but you're passing up an object with a property that is a list. Try sending up the array directly, it should map to List

```
CustomAjaxRequest("Post", "@Url.Action("UpdateOrderHoldingsForSections", "Renewal")" , 
     sectionsOrder, "json", "UpdateSectionsViewWithLatestOrderHoldings", 
           null, true);
```

Or you could instead add a C# binding model which has a property `public List<OrderHoldings> Sections { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(sectionsOrder);            
var dataObject = { sections: jsonData };            
CustomAjaxRequest("Post", "@Url.Action("UpdateOrderHoldingsForSections", "Renewal")" , dataObject, "json", "UpdateSectionsViewWithLatestOrderHoldings", null, true);
```

And then in controller,

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateOrderHoldingsForSections(string sections)
    {
        List<OrderHoldings> sectionsHoldings;
        JavaScriptSerializer seriliazer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        sectionsHoldings = seriliazer.Deserialize<List<OrderHoldings>>(sections);
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

and yes, make sure that you are accepting string in the controller as seen above and not List

Comment: You're completely bypassing model binding there and would therefore not have any of the benefits of model validation